File set up for bootstrap customization using sass
Hi I am trying to setup bootstrap for cuztomization using sass, I have created a html page and then when i am adding my own custom properties on the custom.scss file they dont seem to have any effect on my page.
to the best of my knowledge i have tried step by step guidance using missing bootsrap 5 textbook, then i tried using bootstrap 5 website itself, but having the same issues in that my custom properties are not being implemented, i have a feeling its the way the project is set up but cant seem to figure out the problem, been trying since yesterday.


First, download files of bootstrap and store them in a folder.
Here's a link for version 5.3.3.
You only need the scss folder with all the scss files in it. Make sure you can compile the file scss/bootstrap.scss into a bootstrap.css using your favorite sass compiler. For example using the extension "Easy Compile" for VS code.
Now it's time to create your main.scss file that will include bootstrap, optionally modify it, and of course can include all your other styles.
main.scss
// overrides for bootstrap:
$primary : #FEBC35;
$body-bg: red;

// include bootstrap
@import "path/to/bootstrap.scss";

// your other styles:
h1 {
  background: blue;
}

Finally, include the compiled main.css in your HTML file
<link rel='stylesheet' href='path/to/main.css'>


Have i not dont this already except i called my file custom.scss ?

Is the output CSS file recently created? Or is it not being compiled?

yes it is generating the customstyle.css file that is on my screenshot but when i make any custom changes on the sass file there seems to be no actual change on my web page?

looking at dev tools network tab can you see your css file being requested and loaded? are you also including bootstrap.css from the cdn by mistake?

Hi sorry i wasnt aware i dont have to include bootstrap.css from cnd. i commented that out and my custom styles now seem to be taking effect. thank you for your help
